# Poner condiciones a los getter y setter en una clase

Tags: java, poo, clase

Estoy aprendiendo a crear clases y no entiendo como hacer para que al imprimir los objetos de la clase Cliente me aparezcan solo:

- mayores de edad y menores de 120
- Emails que contengan el char " @ "

Tal y como esta ahora me aparecen los datos tal cual los introduzca y me gustaria que se hicieran las modificaciones que introduci en los metodos get/set correspondientes, ya llevo un buen rato intentando sacarlos y no lo consigo.

Gracias por adelantado.

```
public class Mio2{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Cliente c1 = new Cliente();
    Cliente c2 = new Cliente();

    c1.setNombre("Sergio");
    c1.setEdad(15);
    c1.setEmail("Sergio@hotmail.com");
    c1.setOfertas(true);

    c2.setEmail("almaHijo");
    c2.setEdad(154);
    c2.setNombre("Purrian");
    c2.setOfertas(false);

    System.out.println(c1.toString());
    System.out.println(c2.toString());

}

}



package pkg79.mio2;

public class Cliente{

private String nombre;
private int edad;
private String email;
private boolean ofertas;

public Cliente()
{
}

public Cliente(String nombre, int edad, String email, boolean ofertas)
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.email = email;
    this.ofertas = ofertas;
}

public boolean isOfertas()
{
    return ofertas;
}

public void setOfertas(boolean ofertas)
{
    this.ofertas = ofertas;
}

public boolean mayorEdad()
{
    return edad >= 18;
}

public String getNombre()
{
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nome)
{
    this.nombre = nome;
}

public int getEdad()
{
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int idade)
{
    if (this.edad > 120)
    {
        this.edad = 120;
    } else
    {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}

public String getEmail()
{
    if (email.contains("@"))
    {
        return email;
    } else
    {
        return "No hay email";
    }
}

public void setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Cliente{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", email=" + email + ", ofertas=" + ofertas + '}';
}

}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que se validen los datos de las personas antes de crearlas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estas llamando a los getters que ya definistes en tu ToString(). Solo tienes que cambiar el nombre de la variable por su función de getter.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Cliente{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + this.getEdad() + ", email=" + this.getEmail() + ", ofertas=" + ofertas + '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos `get` solo deberían devolver los valores de los atributos de tu clase o una copia de ellos (o propiedades calculadas en base a estos).

Las comprobaciones de atributos (que no sean nulos, vacíos o que tengan ciertas propiedades o formato) las debes hacer en los constructores y en los métodos `set`.

Por tanto, considero tu método `getEmail` como erróneo. En vez de eso, en el constructor compruebas el formato de email, y si no lo cumple puedes o bien cambiarlo a `null`, o bien lanzar una excepción de tipo `IllegalArgumentException`.

De esta forma en tu método `toString` solo tienes que imprimir los campos, comprobando que no sean nulos, de la siguiente manera.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cliente {" + nombre + ", " + (email == null ? "No email" : email) + "}";
}
```

Para que funcione bien, además, tienes que, como he dicho, comprobar la corrección de los parámetros en constructores y setters, y si alguno no cumple las condiciones que consideres correctas, lanzar una excepción, del tipo adecuado (no es recomendable cambiar unos valores por otros y esconder un error, como has hecho, a menos que no lo consideres un error).

```
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    if (nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    if (edad < limiteInferior || edad > limiteSuperior)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.edad = edad;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    if (isEmailValido(email)) this.email = email;
    else this.email = null;    // por ejemplo
}
```

O este último método, podría ser así.

```
public void setEmail(String email) {
    if (!isEmailValido(email))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.email = email;
}
```

El constructor quedaría como sigue (he omitido el atributo `ofertas`).

```
public Cliente(String nombre, int edad, String email) {
    setNombre(nombre);
    setEdad(edad);
    setEmail(email);
}
```